# SpringToolSuite4 - Spring Tools 3 Add Install Error

Tags: java, spring, plugins, spring-tool-suite, marketplace

I was using Spring 4.10.0 version and then re-downloaded it with Spring 4.9.0 due to namespaces error.

However, spring tools 3 add-on for spring tools 4 are not installed in the marketplace. I deleted the version 4.10.0 that I used last time and deleted the existing workspace and re-created it with the same name, but I don't know what the problem is.

In the error log, there is a saying, "The process is not accessible because another process is using the file." Is this a problem? I erased all the previous files, but if this is a problem, how can I solve it? Please help me..

I installed something else (Tern Eclipse~, Eclipse Enterprise Java~) just in case, but there was no problem with the installation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHZsE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SeYn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sc7f.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxGvr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCatv.png)

[enter image description here][6]

- Additional error attachments
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u7Ip.png

Comment: You are using Spring Tool Suite 4, which is version 4 of what you are trying to install. So not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would like to download the spring tools 3 add-on for spring tools 4 from the marketplace to make the spring legacy project. There was a problem in this process, so it won't be installed. Do you want me to explain something else?

Comment: You cannot install on OLD version on a NEW version. STS4 is Spring Tool 4. You don't need an older version to build an older version of a project.

Comment: As far as I know, the spring legacy project cannot be created because STS4 basically supports spring boot.
So I'm going to create a project by installing additional sts3 for 4 tool that supports legacy.
My friends are creating a legacy project in this way and I want to solve the marketplace's install error.

Comment: The legacy project is just a regular maven or gradle project with added dependencies. You don't need STS3 for that, that will work as well (or even better) with STS4. You just don't have the wizard anymore to add dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I want to work in the same environment as the team I'm with, so I'm matching the version and additional attributes with them. Other people don't have any problems with the installation, so I think it's a problem because I don't have mylyn as you can see in the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are referring to the version of the Spring Tool Suite distribution when you mention version 4.9.0 and 4.10.0 above - and not the Spring framework or Spring Boot itself.

That version of the tooling is quite old and the STS3 Add-On pack from the Eclipse marketplace is not compatible with that version.

Please also keep in mind that:

- The support for maintenance updates for Spring IDE and Spring Tool Suite / STS3 has officially ended (https://spring.io/blog/2022/06/14/goodbye-spring-ide-welcome-spring-tools-4), so there will be no version with support for the latest Eclipse or Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse releases.

If you have a so-called legacy project, you should be able to import this into a regular and up-to-date Spring Tools 4 distribution on top of Eclipse 2022-06. This wiki page of the user guide gives you a few hints how to migrate those projects: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/STS3-Migration. Another way would be to import the project as a fresh project into a fresh workspace using "Import -> Existing Maven Projects".

Please note, that the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse tooling is by no means limited to Spring Boot projects. It has certain features that are specifically designed and implemented for Spring Boot, but you can use it to work on any Spring (or even Java) project just fine.

In case you are missing specific tooling features in the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution that would make your life easier working with your legacy project, please tell us and create an enhancement request here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My team uses the same version as me and there is no problem installing the plug-in, so my configuration seems to be a problem.
I added an attached file, but as you can see here, it seems to be a problem caused by the absence of mylyn. Can I know the solution?

Comment: Mylyn doesn't exist anymore for Eclipse 2022-06 and beyond. Spring IDE used Mylyn in the past, which is why you see the error when you try to install that STS3 Add-On Pack.What prevents you from using a plain Spring Tools 4 distribution on the latest Eclipse and import the project as a regular Maven project?

Comment: If you really want an old version in which you can install the STS3 Add-On Pack, you would have to go back to a Spring Tools 4 distribution that is based on Eclipse 2022-03 (or older), avoid an auto-update of that to the latest Eclipse (which usually happens due to Eclipse always trying to update to the latest version), and install the corresponding STS3 Add-On Pack for exactly that Spring Tools 4 and Eclipse platform version. I can provide URLs to those downloads and repos, but would need to know exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: But again, I strongly recommend to upgrade and use a plain Spring Tools 4 installation on top of the latest Eclipse and go from there (without installing STS3 Add-On Packs, which are not maintained anymore). You can use your projects in there as well.